# .Net Core EF - when auto inserting data into table, auto sql code may use merge without id attribute causing error

Tags: .net, attributes, sql-update, ado.net

I'm using [this](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnWeb) project as a template for my web API. I have created tables with their primary and foreign keys and populated them with data. When I try to add data to another new table in the database, for some reason that I can't understand, the framework ignores the auto-indexed attribute "Id". This error causes the autogenerated SQL statement to fail execution because no ID index is provided, given that it's a not null attribute. New data isn't added to the table, although previous data updates to the other tables finish with success.

The class for the entity of the table implements an interface and an object

```
public interface IAggregateRoot
    {
    }
```

```
public abstract class BaseEntity<T>
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; protected set; }
    }
```

that only has "Id" as an attribute.

Here you can see the class,

```
public class Shop_Empleado : BaseEntity<Shop_Empleado>, IAggregateRoot
    {
        public long Ruc { get; set; }
        public string Nombre1 { get; set; }
        public string Nombre2 { get; set; }
        public string Apellido1 { get; set; }
        public string Apellido2 { get;set; }
        public int Edad { get; set; }
        public string Direccion1 { get; set; }
        public string Direccion2 { get; set; }
        public string Nacionalidad { get; set; }
        public string Telefono1 { get; set; }
        public string Telefono2 { get; set;}
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Puesto { get; set; }
        public Shop_Local? Shop_Local { get; set; }
        public int LocalId { get; set; }
        public double Salario { get; set; }
        //public DateTime Fecha_Ingreso { get; set; }
        public bool Iess { get; set; }

        public Shop_Empleado(long Ruc, string Nombre1, string Nombre2, string Apellido1, string Apellido2, 
            int Edad, string Direccion1, string Direccion2, string Nacionalidad, string Telefono1,
            string Puesto, double Salario, bool Iess, string Telefono2 = "-",
            string Email = "-", int LocalId = 1)
        {
            this.Ruc = Ruc;
            this.Nombre1 = Nombre1;
            this.Nombre2 = Nombre2;
            this.Apellido1 = Apellido1;
            this.Apellido2 = Apellido2;
            this.Edad = Edad;
            this.Direccion1 = Direccion1;
            this.Direccion2 = Direccion2;
            this.Nacionalidad = Nacionalidad;
            this.Telefono1 = Telefono1;
            this.Telefono2 = Telefono2;
            this.Email = Email;
            this.Puesto = Puesto;
            this.Salario = Salario;
            //this.Fecha_Ingreso = Fecha_Ingreso;
            this.Iess = Iess;
            this.LocalId = LocalId;
        }
```

configuration,

```
public class Shop_Empleado_Configurations : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Shop_Empleado>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Shop_Empleado> builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable("Shop_Empleado");

            builder.Property(ai => ai.Id)
                .UseHiLo("shop_empleado_hilo")
                .IsRequired();

            builder.Property(ai => ai.Ruc)
                .IsRequired(true)
                .HasColumnType("bigint");

            builder.Property(ai => ai.Nombre1)
                .IsRequired(true)
                .HasMaxLength(25);

            builder.Property(ai => ai.Nombre2)
                .IsRequired(true)
                .HasMaxLength(25);

            builder.Property(ai => ai.Apellido1)
                .IsRequired(true)
                .HasMaxLength(25);

            builder.Property(ai => ai.Apellido2)
                .IsRequired(true)
                .HasMaxLength(25);

            builder.Property(ai => ai.Edad)
                .IsRequired(true)
                .HasColumnType("integer");

            builder.Property(ai => ai.Direccion1)
                .IsRequired(true)
                .HasMaxLength(90);

            builder.Property(ai => ai.Direccion2)
                .IsRequired(true)
                .HasMaxLength(90);

            builder.Property(ai => ai.Nacionalidad)
                .IsRequired(true)
                .HasMaxLength(30);

            builder.Property(ai => ai.Telefono1)
                .IsRequired(true)
                .HasMaxLength(12);

            builder.Property(ai => ai.Telefono2)
                .IsRequired(false)
                .HasMaxLength(12);

            builder.Property(ai => ai.Email)
                .IsRequired(false)
                .HasMaxLength(100);

            builder.Property(ai => ai.Puesto)
                .IsRequired(true)
                .HasMaxLength(35);

            builder.HasOne(ai => ai.Shop_Local)
                .WithMany()
                .HasPrincipalKey(ci => ci.Id)
                .IsRequired(true);

            builder.Property(ai => ai.Salario)
                .IsRequired (true)
                .HasColumnType ("decimal(6,2)");

            //builder.Property(ai => ai.Fecha_Ingreso)
            //    .IsRequired (true)
            //    .HasColumnType ("datetime2(7)");

            builder.Property(ai => ai.Iess)
                .IsRequired(true)
                .HasColumnType("bit");


        }
```

and InitialModel

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
//Creacion Tabla Empleado
            migrationBuilder.CreateSequence(
                name: "shop_empleado_hilo",
                incrementBy: 10);

            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Shop_Empleado",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                    Ruc = table.Column<long>(type: "bigint", maxLength: 13, nullable: false),
                    Nombre1 = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(25)", maxLength: 35, nullable: false),
                    Nombre2 = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(25)", maxLength: 35, nullable: false),
                    Apellido1 = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(25)", maxLength: 35, nullable: false),
                    Apellido2 = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(25)", maxLength: 35, nullable: false),
                    Edad = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                    Direccion1 = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(90)", maxLength: 90, nullable: false),
                    Direccion2 = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(90)", maxLength: 90, nullable: false),
                    Nacionalidad = table.Column<int>(type: "nvarchar(30)", maxLength: 30, nullable: false),
                    Telefono1 = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(12)", maxLength: 12, nullable: false),
                    Telefono2 = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(12)", maxLength: 12, nullable: true),
                    Email = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(100)", maxLength: 100, nullable: false),
                    Puesto = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(35)", maxLength: 35, nullable: false),
                    LocalId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
                    Salario = table.Column<double>(type: "decimal(6,2)", nullable: false),
                    //Fecha_Ingreso = table.Column<DateTime>(type: "datetime2(7)", maxLength: 7, nullable: false),
                    Iess = table.Column<bool>(type: "bit", nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Shop_Empleado", x => x.Id);
                    //table.ForeignKey("FK_Shop_Local_Shop_LocalId",
                    //    column: x => x.LocalId,
                    //    principalTable: "Shop_Local",
                    //    principalColumn: "Id",
                    //    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });
        }
```

files that create the database table and configure the entity. The files template has been used for other tables and objects successfully. For this specific entity, the auto-generated SQL ignores the ID attribute.

Error prompt:

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM [Shop_Empleado] AS [s]) THEN CAST(1 AS bit)
    ELSE CAST(0 AS bit)
END
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command: Information: Executed DbCommand (7ms) [Parameters=[@p0='?' (Size = 25), @p1='?' (Size = 25), @p2='?' (Size = 90), @p3='?' (Size = 90), @p4='?' (DbType = Int32), @p5='?' (Size = 100), @p6='?' (DbType = Boolean), @p7='?' (DbType = Int32), @p8='?' (Size = 30), @p9='?' (Size = 25), @p10='?' (Size = 25), @p11='?' (Size = 35), @p12='?' (DbType = Int64), @p13='?' (Precision = 6) (Scale = 2) (DbType = Decimal), @p14='?' (Size = 12), @p15='?' (Size = 12), @p16='?' (Size = 25), @p17='?' (Size = 25), @p18='?' (Size = 90), @p19='?' (Size = 90), @p20='?' (DbType = Int32), @p21='?' (Size = 100), @p22='?' (DbType = Boolean), @p23='?' (DbType = Int32), @p24='?' (Size = 30), @p25='?' (Size = 25), @p26='?' (Size = 25), @p27='?' (Size = 35), @p28='?' (DbType = Int64), @p29='?' (Precision = 6) (Scale = 2) (DbType = Decimal), @p30='?' (Size = 12), @p31='?' (Size = 12), @p32='?' (Size = 25), @p33='?' (Size = 25), @p34='?' (Size = 90), @p35='?' (Size = 90), @p36='?' (DbType = Int32), @p37='?' (Size = 100), @p38='?' (DbType = Boolean), @p39='?' (DbType = Int32), @p40='?' (Size = 30), @p41='?' (Size = 25), @p42='?' (Size = 25), @p43='?' (Size = 35), @p44='?' (DbType = Int64), @p45='?' (Precision = 6) (Scale = 2) (DbType = Decimal), @p46='?' (Size = 12), @p47='?' (Size = 12)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF;
SET NOCOUNT ON;
MERGE [Shop_Empleado] USING (
VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9, @p10, @p11, @p12, @p13, @p14, @p15, 0),
(@p16, @p17, @p18, @p19, @p20, @p21, @p22, @p23, @p24, @p25, @p26, @p27, @p28, @p29, @p30, @p31, 1),
(@p32, @p33, @p34, @p35, @p36, @p37, @p38, @p39, @p40, @p41, @p42, @p43, @p44, @p45, @p46, @p47, 2)) AS i ([Apellido1], [Apellido2], [Direccion1], [Direccion2], [Edad], [Email], [Iess], [LocalId], [Nacionalidad], [Nombre1], [Nombre2], [Puesto], [Ruc], [Salario], [Telefono1], [Telefono2], _Position) ON 1=0
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT ([Apellido1], [Apellido2], [Direccion1], [Direccion2], [Edad], [Email], [Iess], [LocalId], [Nacionalidad], [Nombre1], [Nombre2], [Puesto], [Ruc], [Salario], [Telefono1], [Telefono2])
VALUES (i.[Apellido1], i.[Apellido2], i.[Direccion1], i.[Direccion2], i.[Edad], i.[Email], i.[Iess], i.[LocalId], i.[Nacionalidad], i.[Nombre1], i.[Nombre2], i.[Puesto], i.[Ruc], i.[Salario], i.[Telefono1], i.[Telefono2])
OUTPUT INSERTED.[Id], i._Position;
'iisexpress.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\7.0.3\System.Reflection.Metadata.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update: Error: An exception occurred in the database while saving changes for context type 'Infrastructure.Data.Shop_Context'.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
 ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table 'SagaMotors_API.CatalogDb.dbo.Shop_Empleado'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryHasMoreRows(Boolean& moreRows)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadInternal(Boolean setTimeout, Boolean& more)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ReadAsyncExecute(Task task, Object state)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.InvokeAsyncCall[T](SqlDataReaderAsyncCallContext`1 context)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ConsumeResultSetAsync(Int32 startCommandIndex, RelationalDataReader reader, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ConsumeAsync(RelationalDataReader reader, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
ClientConnectionId:0b3a38fc-9621-4ae5-8cda-5cbef60dd43c
Error Number:515,State:2,Class:16
```

I'm not new to C# and .NET, neither a professional. Can someone help me with this annoying issue, please?

I have tried to use the files template shown because they succeeded in creating and adding data to table entities. I was hoping the framework auto-generate the same SQL statements as with other cases, but it ignores the "ID" attribute. The error states that the ID can't be null, but the value for ID is never given in the satement.

Also, I don't know why the SQL statement tries to output inserted ID when it should auto index that attribute. As you can see in the promot, the SQL never gaves some value to ID in the statement.

Answer (score 0):

So, after some good eight houres of rest and reading carefully through the code, I found that the problem was about a foreing key my table was referencing. The core of the problem was in the configuration file were you configure the type, keys and data requirements. As you can see in the given code, I was erroneouslly trying to set a Primary Key in the "LocalId" were I had to use a foreing key. This error makes .NET core to try with a Merge Sql operation when inserting data. Also that error in coding makes .NET to ignore the ID attribute that was intendet to be the default index and primary key. The correct code is:

```
builder.HasOne(ai => ai.Shop_Local)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(ci => ci.LocalId)
            .IsRequired(true);
```

Please note that method "HasForeingKey()" is used instead of "HasPrimaryKey()" and that the member "LocalId" of the entity class is replacing "Id" member .